# Parsing Data from android Sign Up page to webView Sign Up page

Tags: android, webview, web

I'm new android developer, I don't have any great idea.

I wanna make app that will take some input from users then will pass those input to a website for sign up & then 
when press Sign Up button from my app button will hit the website Sign Up button.

But I don't know how to do that.

I was search on web long time, but maximum was use JavaScript, I don't have idea about that.

Can anyone please clear me this things please.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You may not get a great response here without some code you have written yourself, your question is going to be closed as not constructive.  I suggest posting on the android forums and not here.

Answer (score 2):

Its not at possible to have 2 views as in one screen. Its possible if you create some API on your website to which you **Send the data to server and in return it will give you true or false, to track data insertion succeded or not.**

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that if the website don't provide the api service.